# Problem running smlnj under OSX 10.6

Tags: macos, sml, smlnj

I downloaded and installed the SML NJ implementation using the DMG for x86 from here :
http://smlnj.cs.uchicago.edu/dist/working/110.72/index.html

However when I open a terminal window and go to /usr/local/smlnj-110.72/bin and run sml i get a bash command not found.
I am not very familiar with UNIX so I guess I am doing something wrong.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 10):

Add the following line to your ~/.bash_profile

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/smlnj/bin
```

Then open a new terminal window and run sml.

Comment: Thanks for this! Perfect!

Answer (score 9):

After going to the `/usr/local/smlnj-xxx/bin` directory, you need to run `./sml` 
(as opposed to `sml`) because the current directory (`.`) is not on the default path on Unix.